# Top down with memoization require larger table size

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I am not able to get it that how top down with memoization requires larger table size as both the approaches bottom up and top down are calculating the problem in 0(n) time complexity and no matter what the way they are doing but the table size will remain same as they are storing the result of n Fibonacci  terms in the table in case of Fibonacci problem
It may have risk of stack overflow in case of top down but table size should remain same??

Comment: The question is a bit difficult to understand; are you referring to the evaluation of the Fibonacci sequence in particular? If so, there seems to be some misconception: if evaluation is implemented as top-down with memoization, both the time an space complexity are the same as for bottom-up evaluation, which is also termed dynamic programming by some. However, if top-down with memoization is used, some information is contained in the call stack, which is not the case for bottom-up evaluation - do you mean that?

Comment: Then what could be the benefits of choosing bottom up approach than top down? N yes i am particularly talking about fibonacci series n i have read somewhere that top down require a larger table size

Comment: 1. Some programming languages do not directly support recursive function calls. 2. Top-down requires some mechanism to determine if the desired intermediate result is already calculated, which is eliminated in bottom-up. 3. Top-down potentially suffers from the limitations of a bound on the call stack, which is not the case for bottom-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you can implement bottom-up Fibonacci with only O(1) space.
In python-pseudocode :

```
u=1
v=0
while n>0:
    u,v = v,u+v
    n=n-1
return v
```

Comment: To my understanding, this is bottom-up.